# button to delete rows deletes itself as well

Tags: button, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet that I am using as my to do list and I have added buttons to each row that I can click to delete the row (on the original sheet and a sheet that references it) once the task is assigned.  The buttons are each linked to a function that deletes that specific row, but when I click the button, it also deletes itself (presumably because it is within the row that is being deleted).  This then shifts all the other buttons by one row, resulting in their script referring to the row below instead of the row they are contained in.

Does anyone know how to prevent this?  Is there a way to protect the button/drawing so that it is not deleted when the row is deleted?  Is there a way to anchor the button/drawing to a spot so it is always in x row?  Below is a picture of the spreadsheet and a sample of the code I wrote for one of the buttons.

```
//The following functions delete indicated row AFTER header
function DeleteSecondLine() {

 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[1];
 sheet.deleteRow(3);

 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0]
 sheet.deleteRow(3); 
}
```

Image of Spreadsheet:
[image]

Comment: Instead of deleting the row, you could overwrite its content with that of the next row, and so on, and then call `clearContents()` on the final row. I.e. `kept = range(4, 1, N, C).getValues()` and `range(3, 1, N, C).setValues(kept)` and `range(getLastRow(), 1, 1, C).clearContent()`. A different solution that still does deleting but does not use drawings could also be done (e.g. writing &quot;delete&quot; in a specific cell + an `onEdit` function that checks if the range is the special range, and if the value is &quot;delete&quot;, then deletes that row).

Comment: pnuts - I'd want the button to stay put and basically refer to the new contents of that row.  (i.e. I delete the third item on the list, all other items shift upwards, and that button now refers to the task that was previously the fourth item on the list.

Comment: tehhowch - I'm pretty new at this still.  I understand the concept of what you are saying, but I am trying to figure out what it ends up looking like in the code.  Forgive the noviceness of this post.  Any help appreciated.  Here is where I have gotten so far, but keep getting errors.
  
    function OverwriteRow() {
  
     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
     var sheet = ss.getSheets()[1];
     var kept = sheet.range(4, 1, N, C).getValues(); 
     sheet.range(3, 1, N, C).setValues(kept);
     sheet.range(getLastRow(), 1, 1, C).clearContent(); 
    }

Comment: pnuts - Just renumber them by rewriting the code each time?